# Insert data into temp table, multiple columns from one Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with columns: `ID` (Int), `Date` (Date) and `Price` (Decimal). `Date` column is in format 2013-04-14:

### Table Example

```
ID      Date        Price
    1       2012/05/02  23.5
    1       2012/05/03  25.2
    1       2012/05/04  22.5
    1       2012/05/05  22.2
    1       2012/05/06  26.5
    2       2012/05/02  143.5
    2       2012/05/03  145.2
    2       2012/05/04  142.2
    2       2012/05/05  146.5
    3       2012/05/02  83.5
    3       2012/05/03  85.2
    3       2012/05/04  80.5
```

### Query Example:

I want to be able to select all `ID`1 and `ID`3's data between a date range from the table and have this in a table with three columns, ordered by `Date` column.  Also I would want to insert this into a temporary table to perform mathematical calculations on the data. Please comment if there is a better way.

Correct Result Example

```
Date        ID1     ID3
2012-05-02  23.5    83.5    
2012-05-03  25.2    85.2    
2012-05-04  22.5    80.2
```

Any help and advice will be appreciated,

Thanks

---

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MS SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: I don't understand where your “correct results” are coming from. Neither your sample data nor query have rows for 2012-05-02, but your results have them. Your query selects two columns, but your results have three. Price for ID 1 on 2012/05/03 is 23.5, but your “correct results” show 318.69.

Comment: Question is now edited to take into account

Comment: What if you had more than one row with the same `ID` and `Date`? Should the `Prices` be added? Only one chosen? If you think there shouldn't be, what should happen if there were?

Comment: If there were more than one price for the same ID and Date that would be an error in the data - that should never be the case.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
  Date date,
  x money,
  y money
  )
;

SELECT
 Date,
 MAX(CASE WHEN id=1 THEN price END) AS x,
 MAX(CASE WHEN id=3 THEN price END) AS y
FROM Top40
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-05-02' AND '2012-05-04'
GROUP BY 
 Date
;
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f2f0/4) for working example

**EDIT:**
To use the LAG window function on the x and y columns, you'll have to use a common table expression or CTE first.

```
WITH prices AS(
SELECT
 Date as myDate,
 MAX(CASE WHEN id=1 THEN price END) AS x,
 MAX(CASE WHEN id=3 THEN price END) AS y
FROM Top40
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-05-02' AND '2012-05-04'
GROUP BY 
 Date
 )
SELECT
 myDate,
 p.x,
 (p.x/(LAG(p.x) OVER (ORDER BY MyDate))-1) as x_return,
 p.y,
 (p.y/(LAG(p.y) OVER (ORDER BY MyDate))-1) as y_return
FROM prices p
ORDER BY
 myDate
;
```

See new [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f2f0/9) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it in code (although it may not perform well with large data sets) is to do something like:

```
SELECT [Date], x = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN PRICE END)
, y = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 3 THEN PRICE END)
INTO #tmp
FROM Top40
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
select Date , t1.Price as Stock_1_Price , t2.Price as Stock_3_price
from      ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 1 group by "Date" ) t1
full join ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 3 group by "Date" ) t2 on t2.Date = t1.Date
```

As far as populating a temp table, any of the usual ways works:

- Table variable:

  ```
  declare @work table
  (
    yyyymmdd      varchar(32) not null ,
    stock_1_price money null ,
    stock_3_price money null
  )

  insert @work ( yyyymmdd , stock_1_price , stock_3_price )
  select Date , t1.Price as Stock_1_Price , t2.Price as Stock_3_price
  from      ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 1 group by "Date" ) t1
  full join ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 3 group by "Date" ) t2 on t2.Date = t1.Date
  ```
- Declared temp table in tempdb

  ```
  create table #work
  (
    yyyymmdd      varchar(32) not null primary key clustered ,
    stock_1_price money null ,
    stock_3_price money null
  )

  insert #work ( yyyymmdd , stock_1_price , stock_3_price )
  select Date , t1.Price as Stock_1_Price , t2.Price as Stock_3_price
  from      ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 1 group by "Date" ) t1
  full join ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 3 group by "Date" ) t2 on t2.Date = t1.Date
  ```
- non-declare temp table in tempdb via `select into`:

  ```
  select Date , t1.Price as Stock_1_Price , t2.Price as Stock_3_price
  into #work
  from      ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 1 group by "Date" ) t1
  full join ( select "Date" , max(Price) as Price from myData where ID = 3 group by "Date" ) t2 on t2.Date = t1.Date
  ```

Comment: It works thanks, though no date Where clause to specify range